# use case multiple generalization

Tags: uml, use-case, generalization

Is it possible to have a generalization like the one in the image attached in use cases?[image]

Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The next question is : Does it make sense?

Comment: My system is more complex than the image. In the documentation of UML I couldn't find anything about this. Have you a link where this is explained better?

Comment: @ajeje93 Red is absolutely right. You can do it, But whether it makes sense? Only you can decide upon that.

Comment: Explain what? The generalization link?

Comment: @RedBeard No, I mean when to use a generalization like in the image, but as Thomas pointed out it depends on what you are modeling.